# how to play sound on button

Tags: java, android, audio

i'm the newbie this my code
the sound is not play but when i click the button the toast is show
anyone help me??

```
public class DB_Parse extends Activity {

MediaPlayer mp;
Button button;
int ,sound;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.keterangan);


    final int sound = iIdentifikasi.getIntExtra("dataID", 0);

    button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnsound);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override    
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (sound==1){
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.munfasil);
                mp.start();

            }

                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                                   "Sound is Play", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

});

}

}
```

if (sound==1) 1 from _id in sqlite

Comment: put a log statement and check what is the value of sound you are getting

Comment: log.i("Sound=",""+sound); after final int sound = iIdentifikasi.getIntExtra("dataID", 0);

Comment: glad to help you vote up..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all you are declaring your variable sound twice. 
Please change:

```
 final int sound = iIdentifikasi.getIntExtra("dataID", 0);
```

for

```
 sound = iIdentifikasi.getIntExtra("dataID", 0);
```

The other thing that you should try is changing the toast  inside your if, so you are sure that sound is 1.

```
       if (sound==1){
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.munfasil);
            mp.start();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                               "Sound is Play", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
```

If toast is not displaying your int sound is not 1.

Comment: We you vote down? This answer was the only one that really helps for your code, im using your code and telling you whats happening a where is the problem.

Comment: how to stop sound by press back..  i want to stop my sound being played from when my Activity is paused..i mean stay in my activty..

Answer (score 1):

try this way it will work

```
  public class DB_Parse extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.v(TAG, "Initializing sounds...");

    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.youraudio);

    Button play_button = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.play_button);
    play_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Playing sound...");
            mp.start();
        }
    });
    Log.v(TAG, "Sounds initialized.");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your audio/media file in asset folder instead putting into raw folder and follow above snippet, its working quite fine for me..

```
try
{
   AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("your_media_file_name.mp3");
   MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
   mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
   mp.prepare();
   mp.start();
}
catch(Exception e)
{ e.printStackTrace();}
```

Fire it on your button click event